# Displaying seconds as days/hours/mins/seconds?

Tags: bash

Is it possible to easily format seconds as a human-readable time in bash?

I don't want to format it as a date, but as the number of days/hours/minutes, etc...

Comment: Could you provide an example/several examples please?

Comment: Are you saying you have an interval, or a date since the epoch?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
function displaytime {
  local T=$1
  local D=$((T/60/60/24))
  local H=$((T/60/60%24))
  local M=$((T/60%60))
  local S=$((T%60))
  (( $D > 0 )) && printf '%d days ' $D
  (( $H > 0 )) && printf '%d hours ' $H
  (( $M > 0 )) && printf '%d minutes ' $M
  (( $D > 0 || $H > 0 || $M > 0 )) && printf 'and '
  printf '%d seconds\n' $S
}
```

Examples:

```
$ displaytime 11617
3 hours 13 minutes and 37 seconds
$ displaytime 42
42 seconds
$ displaytime 666
11 minutes and 6 seconds
```

Comment: This is really nice — the only thing it's missing is dropping the -s from singular day(s), hour(s), minute(s) and second(s).

Answer (score 34):

Easiest and cleanest way is this one liner (here assuming GNU `date`):

If the number of seconds is, say:

```
seconds=123456789 # as in one of the answers above

date -ud "@$seconds" +"$(( $seconds/3600/24 )) days %H hours %M minutes %S seconds"
```

--> output: `1428 days 21 hours 33 minutes 09 seconds`

Comment: If your duration will always be less than a day you can use `+%T` format for Hours:Minutes:Seconds for this `date +%T "1970-01-01 + ${seconds} seconds"` to get `21:33:09`

Comment: @YzmirRamirez your command is unnecessarily complicated because it factors in the timezone... more straight forward would be still with `-u` to simply stay in UTC since it is only a duration: `date -u +"%T" -d "@${seconds}"`.

Comment: Pretty nice answer especially when combined with @DJCrashdummy comment! 

Answer (score 12):

Credit goes to **Stéphane Gimenez** but if someone would like to display seconds only if a period is less than a minute here is my modified version that I use (also with fixed pluralization):

```
converts()
{
    local t=$1

    local d=$((t/60/60/24))
    local h=$((t/60/60%24))
    local m=$((t/60%60))
    local s=$((t%60))

    if [[ $d > 0 ]]; then
            [[ $d = 1 ]] && echo -n "$d day " || echo -n "$d days "
    fi
    if [[ $h > 0 ]]; then
            [[ $h = 1 ]] && echo -n "$h hour " || echo -n "$h hours "
    fi
    if [[ $m > 0 ]]; then
            [[ $m = 1 ]] && echo -n "$m minute " || echo -n "$m minutes "
    fi
    if [[ $d = 0 && $h = 0 && $m = 0 ]]; then
            [[ $s = 1 ]] && echo -n "$s second" || echo -n "$s seconds"
    fi  
    echo
}
```

An alternative example in POSIX:

```
converts(){
    t=$1

    d=$((t/60/60/24))
    h=$((t/60/60%24))
    m=$((t/60%60))
    s=$((t%60))

    if [ $d -gt 0 ]; then
            [ $d = 1 ] && printf "%d day " $d || printf "%d days " $d
    fi
    if [ $h -gt 0 ]; then
            [ $h = 1 ] && printf "%d hour " $h || printf "%d hours " $h
    fi
    if [ $m -gt 0 ]; then
            [ $m = 1 ] && printf "%d minute " $m || printf "%d minutes " $m
    fi
    if [ $d = 0 ] && [ $h = 0 ] && [ $m = 0 ]; then
            [ $s = 1 ] && printf "%d second" $s || printf "%d seconds" $s
    fi
    printf '\n'
}
```

Comment: This worked really well. I simply pasted the function into my script and ran `convert $s` to get pretty output.

Answer (score 6):

I'd do it like this:

```
$ seconds=123456789; echo $((seconds/86400))" days "$(date -d "1970-01-01 + $seconds seconds" "+%H hours %M minutes %S seconds")
1428 days 21 hours 33 minutes 09 seconds
$
```

Here's the one liner above, broken down so that it's easier to understand:

```
$ seconds=123456789
$ echo $((seconds/86400))" days"\
     $(date -d "1970-01-01 + $seconds seconds" "+%H hours %M minutes %S seconds")
```

In the above I'm echoing out the output of another command that's run inside the `$( ... )` sub-command. That sub-command is doing this, calculating the number of days (seconds/86400), then using the `date` command in another sub-command `$(date -d ... )`, to generate the hours, minutes, and seconds for a given number of seconds.

Comment: why are you adding an unnecessary `echo`? and factoring in the timezone also makes no sense! **||** much easier would be `date -u +"$(( ${seconds} / 86400 )) days %H hours %M minutes %S seconds" -d "@${seconds}"`.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy, thank you for asking. It is the first solution that uses 'date' to do the calculations, and it's not without its flaws. I deeply appreciate the contributions from all commenters who have enhanced this method.

Answer (score 4):

I'm building on atti's answer which I liked as an idea.

You can do this with the bash builtin `printf` which will take  the seconds since the epoch as an argument. No need to fork  to run `date`.

You have to set the timezone to UTC for `printf` because it formats the time in your local timezone and you will get the wrong answer if you are not in UTC time.

```bsh
$ seconds=123456789
$ TZ=UTC printf "%d days %(%H hours %M minutes %S seconds)T\n" $((seconds/86400)) $seconds
1428 days 21 hours 33 minutes 09 seconds
```

In my local time (which is currently NZDT - +1300) the answer is wrong if I do not set the timezone

```
$ seconds=123456789
$ printf "%d days %(%H hours %M minutes %S seconds)T\n" $((seconds/86400)) $seconds
1428 days 09 hours 33 minutes 09 seconds
```

With and without setting the timezone

```
$ seconds=$(( 3600 * 25))
$ printf "%d days %(%H hours %M minutes %S seconds)T\n" $((seconds/86400)) $seconds
1 days 13 hours 00 minutes 00 seconds

$ TZ=UTC printf "%d days %(%H hours %M minutes %S seconds)T\n" $((seconds/86400)) $seconds
1 days 01 hours 00 minutes 00 seconds
```

Comment: Note that bash's `printf` introduced this `%(datefmt)T` notation beginning with bash-4.2-alpha.

Answer (score 3):

I modified the displaytime function above... as follows:

```
seconds2time ()
{
   T=$1
   D=$((T/60/60/24))
   H=$((T/60/60%24))
   M=$((T/60%60))
   S=$((T%60))

   if [[ ${D} != 0 ]]
   then
      printf '%d days %02d:%02d:%02d' $D $H $M $S
   else
      printf '%02d:%02d:%02d' $H $M $S
   fi
}
```

because I always want to see HH:MM:SS, even if they are zeros.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, to get an output in `[[[[d and ]hh:]mm:]ss | ss 's']` format it could be done like this:

```bsh
function format_seconds() {
  (($1 >= 86400)) && printf '%d days and ' $(($1 / 86400)) # days
  (($1 >= 3600)) && printf '%02d:' $(($1 / 3600 % 24))     # hours
  (($1 >= 60)) && printf '%02d:' $(($1 / 60 % 60))         # minutes
  printf '%02d%s\n' $(($1 % 60)) "$( (($1 < 60 )) && echo ' s.' || echo '')"
}
```

For example, if we execute:

```bsh
format_seconds 1000000
format_seconds 86450
format_seconds 9000
format_seconds 2500
format_seconds 60
format_seconds 34
```

We will get the following output:

```
11 days and 13:46:40
1 days and 00:00:50
02:30:00
41:40
01:00
34 s.
```

Although the question was asked more than 8 years ago i hope it helps to someone :)

Answer (score 1):

Building on **Stéphane Gimenez's** answer, but an alternative to **dimir's**:

Since printf is already in play, may as well use %s and pass is the s (or not) to pluralize when needed:

```
displaytime() {
  local T=$1
  local D=$((T/60/60/24))
  local H=$((T/60/60%24))
  local M=$((T/60%60))
  local S=$((T%60))
  (( $D > 0 )) && printf '%d day%s ' $D $( (( $D > 1 )) && echo s)
  (( $H > 0 )) && printf '%d hour%s ' $H $( (( $H > 1 )) && echo s)
  (( $M > 0 )) && printf '%d minute%s ' $M $( (( $M > 1 )) && echo s)
  (( $D > 0 || $H > 0 || $M > 0 )) && printf 'and '
  printf '%d second%s\n' $S $( (( $S != 1 )) && echo s)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I slightly improved [@Jacques' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338844/85408) into this:

```bash
FormatSeconds () { 
  seconds="$1"
  date -ud @${seconds} +"$(( seconds/3600/24 ))d %-Hh %-Mm %-Ss" \
    | sed -E 's/\b0(s|m|h|d) ?//g; s/ +$//; s/^$/0s/'
}
```

which will just use "d/h/m/s", strip off leading zeroes and omit zero parts. So:

```
> FormatSeconds 123456789
1428d 21h 33m 9s
> FormatSeconds $((1 * 24 * 60 * 60 + 60 + 1))
1d 1m 1s
```

Comment: +1 for the idea with `sed`, but your implementation is way too complicated! **||** `date` can prevent leading 0 by itself with `%-` and this makes the sed part even more easier than it could be already: `date -u +"$(( ${seconds} / 86400 ))d %-Hh %-Mmin %-Ss" -d "@${seconds}" | sed -E -e 's/\<0(d|h|min|s)\> ?//g ; s/^$/0s/'`

Comment: BTW: the 2nd `seconds` in your `date`-command misses at least a preceded `$`! even better would be `${seconds}`.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy The second `seconds` does not need a `$` because that's how arithmetic evaluation works, see e.g. `bash -c 'ONE=1 ; echo $((ONE + 1))'` .

Comment: @DJCrashdummy Your version of the command leaves an extra blank at the end for `seconds=$((60*60+60))`.

Comment: i just wanted to be on the safe side with the parameter expansion, since it can't be about execution time... else you would write `.../86400` instead of `.../3600/24` and use `${1}` straight instead of `${seconds}`.

Comment: you are right about the subsequent space! i didn't pay attention to it since my goal was to omit only leading units with value 0 (which is even easier: `...| sed -E -e 's/^(\<0(d|h|min)\> )*//g'`). **||** side note: perhaps using `[[:space:]]` instead of a literal ` ` in the sed script would be worth considering to be on the safe side... but this is me being extra cautious and trying to produce overly portable code because with this piped date command it is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

Here one

```
secs=378444
echo $(($secs/86400))d $(($(($secs - $secs/86400*86400))/3600))h:$(($(($secs - $secs/86400*86400))%3600/60))m:$(($(($secs - $secs/86400*86400))%60))s
```

Output:

```
4d 9h:7m:24s
```

Answer (score -3):

`date --date '@1005454800'` gives you `Sun Nov 11 00:00:00 EST 2001`, which is 1005454800 seconds after the Unix epoch.  You can format that with the date +FORMAT option.

Comment: That's a date, not a duration, which the question was asking about.