# how to calculate time taken (elapsed time) by loop

Tags: bash, time, for

Hello Every one I have script that call other script with while loop
I need to know how to calculate time taken by each loop
 like :

```
Starting NodeManager...
NodeManager Started
Elapsed time: 00:00:10

Starting AdminServer...
AdminServer Started
Elapsed time: 00:01:10
```

here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
clear

TFILE=starting.log
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Check_Status_NM ()
{
tail -F ${TFILE} | while read LOGLINE
do
    if [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Secure socket listener started on port"* ]] 
    then
    pkill -P $$ tail
    break
    elif [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Address already in use"*  ]]; then
    pkill -P $$ tail
    echo -e "Cannot Start Server\nSee starting.log for more info "
    exit 1
    fi
done
}
#----------------------------------------------------------------
Check_Status ()
{
tail -F ${TFILE} | while read LOGLINE
do
    if [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"* ]] ; then
    echo -e "\e[5m\e[93mWARNING\e[0m Could not establish the connection\n\e[91mCheck Connection to Database\e[0m\n"
    elif [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"<Server started in RUNNING mode>"* ]] 
    then
    pkill -P $$ tail && cat /dev/null > ${TFILE}
  sleep 1
    break

    elif [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"<Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN>"* ]] || [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Address already in use"*  ]]; then
    pkill -P $$ tail
    echo -e "\e[91mCannot Start Server\e[0m\nSee starting.log for more info "
    exit 1
    fi
done
}
export JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.management.username=weblogic -Dweblogic.management.password=oracle11g"
#-------Start NodeManager-------------------------------------------------------
echo -e "Starting NodeManager..."
nohup "$WLS_HOME"/server/bin/startNodeManager.sh  > ${TFILE} 2>&1 &
Check_Status_NM
echo -e "NodeManager \e[92mStarted\e[0m\n"
#--------------------------Start WebLogic Domain------------------------------------------------
echo -e "Starting AdminServer..." 
nohup "$DOMAIN_HOME"/bin/setDomainEnv.sh > ${TFILE} 2>&1 &
nohup "$DOMAIN_HOME"/bin/startWebLogic.sh > ${TFILE} 2>&1 &
Check_Status
echo -e "AdminServer \e[92mStarted\e[0m\n"
#----------- Start FORMS------------------------------
echo "Starting Forms Server..."
nohup "$DOMAIN_HOME"/bin/startManagedWebLogic.sh WLS_FORMS t3://$(hostname):7001 > ${TFILE} 2>&1 &
Check_Status
echo "Forms Server \e[92mStarted\e[0m\n"
#----------- Start Reports------------------------------
echo -e "Starting Reports Server..."
nohup "$DOMAIN_HOME"/bin/startManagedWebLogic.sh WLS_REPORTS t3://$(hostname):7001 > ${TFILE} 2>&1 &
Check_Status
echo -e "Reports Server \e[92mStarted\e[0m\n"
#---------------------Start anything remaining using OPMN------------------------
opmnctl startall ; opmnctl status ; emctl start agent
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bash has a built in "timer". Set the `SECONDS` variable to 0 (zero) when you want to start timing, and read its value to get the number of seconds elapsed since it was last reset.

Comment: thanks...it worked but can you tell me how to make it show like
Elapsed time: 00:00:10

Comment: @KhalidAboElMaGd Here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27013/displaying-seconds-as-days-hours-mins-seconds

Comment: ...please could you tell me how to show elapsed as a  count in real time..
like a stopwatch?